# Python MySQL search entire database for value

Tags: python, mysql, select, mysql-python

I have a GUI interacting with my database, and MySQL database has around 50 tables. I need to search each table for a value and return the field and key of the item in each table if it is found. I would like to search for partial matches. ex.( Search Value = "test", "Protest", "Test123" would be matches. Here is my attempt.

```
def searchdatabase(self, event):
        print('Searching...')
        self.connect_mysql() #Function to connect to database

        d_tables = [] 
        results_list = [] # I will store results here
        s_string = "test" #Value I am searching

        self.cursor.execute("USE db") # select the database
        self.cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")  
  
        for (table_name,) in self.cursor:
            d_tables.append(table_name)
        
        #Loop through tables list, get column name, and check if value is in the column
        for table in d_tables:
            #Get the columns
            self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{table}` WHERE 1=0")
            field_names = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.description]
           
            #Find Value
            for f_name in field_names:
                print("RESULTS:", self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{table}` WHERE {f_name} LIKE {s_string}"))
                print(table)
```

I get an error on `` print("RESULTS:", self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{table}` WHERE {f_name} LIKE {s_string}")) ``

Exception: (1054, "Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'")

I use a similar insert query that works fine so I am not understanding what the issue is.

ex. `` insert_query = (f"INSERT INTO `{source_tbl}` ({query_columns}) VALUES ({query_placeholders})") ``

Answer (score 0):

May be because of single quote you have missed while checking for some columns.
TRY :

```
print("RESULTS:", self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `{table}` WHERE '{f_name}' LIKE '{s_string}'"))
```

Have a look -> [here](https://tech-assured.com/blog/database-server-support/mysql-error-1054-unknown-column-in-field-list/)

Comment: I added the single quote and it is no longer throwing the Exception. However, it is not returning any of the data I placed in it for a test. It returns "0".

Answer (score 0):

1. Don’t insert user-provided data into SQL queries like this. It is begging for [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your database library will have a way of [sending parameters to queries](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15). Use that.
2. The whole design is fishy. Normally, there should be no need to look for a string across several columns of 50 different tables. Admittedly, sometimes you end up in these situations because of reasons outside your control.

Comment: Each table consists of different events. I need to know which table a user is in which might sometimes be multiple. I am using mySQL and am using a GUI I have built as an interface. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a built in method to search the entire database without using PHPadmin or something which isn't helpful in my case